# need to to substitute 2 car batteries needed for 48v test voltage (guessing ~3A)

Tags: voltage, dc

I plan to use Lithium Ion source eventually but need 48v working voltage to bench test my project (incorporates a leaf blower). I have 2 good car batteries but need to safely substitute the other for at least 40v.

Possible options I am pondering:

1. The 6 or so old batteries hold ~8-10v but I don't know how long.
2. I have a 12v supply for a trailer home that used to work fine but now needs repair.
3. I have an assortment of power supplies from computers etc. Can I wire groups of them in parallel?

Comment: A 60V/3A bench supply is not expensive, and unlike cobbling a bunch of junk together, it will just work.

Comment: series batteries must be matched or each monitored for low V on discharge and overvoltage on charge

Comment: Wiring power supplies in parallel is a sure method for creating  smoke and fire

Comment: This seems like the perfect opportunity to invest in a $50 power supply. It will save you lots of time and frustration trying to get batteries or smaller supplies in series. Additionally, it will be safer.

Comment: Or use the two good 12V batteries with a 24-48V booster. https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-24V-To-DC-48V-3A-144W-Converter-Regulator-Step-Up-Power-Supply-Booster-Module/332373826009?epid=16016475657&hash=item4d630619d9:g:DLoAAOSwYIxX64h8